# Ambiguity with templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

Can someone explain why the following fails to comply due to ambiguity

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename, typename, int> struct foo;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, typename... Us, int I>
struct foo<P<Ts...>, std::tuple<P<Us...>>, I> : foo<P<Ts...>, std::tuple<P<Us...>>, I-1> {};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, typename... Us>
struct foo<P<Ts...>, std::tuple<P<Us...>>, 0> {};

template <typename...> struct P;

int main() {
    foo<P<int, bool, char>, std::tuple<P<>>, 5> a;
}
```

However, the ambiguity is removed if I replace `std::tuple` with `P`.  It is also removed if I replace `P<Ts...>` or `P<Us...>` with, say, a simple type called `Pack`.  I'm using GCC 7.2.  Of course, the ambiguity occurs with `foo<P<int, bool, char>, std::tuple<P<>>, 0>`.  The ambiguity is also removed if I remove the first template from the `foo` definition.

Here is my non-reduced code (well, about 10% reduced).  My reduced code above apparently can be solved by switching the order of the specializations.  Below, switching the order does not work.

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename Pack, typename OutputPack, std::size_t...> struct foo;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Ts, typename... Packs, std::size_t I, std::size_t... Is>
struct foo<P<First, Rest...>, std::tuple<P<Ts...>, Packs...>, I, Is...> :
     foo<P<Rest...>, std::tuple<P<Ts..., First>, Packs...>, I-1, Is...> {};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Ts, typename... Packs, std::size_t I, std::size_t J, std::size_t... Is>
struct foo<P<First, Rest...>, std::tuple<P<Ts...>, Packs...>, 0, I, J, Is...> : 
     foo<P<Rest...>, std::tuple<P<First>, Packs..., P<Ts...>>, I-1, J, Is...> {};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Ts, typename... Packs, std::size_t Last>
struct foo<P<First, Rest...>, std::tuple<P<Ts...>, Packs...>, 0, Last> {};

template <typename...> struct P;

int main() {
    foo<P<int, bool, char, int, long, bool>, std::tuple<P<>>, 1,2,1> a;
}
```

However, replacing `std::tuple` with `P` solves the problem (again) for some reason.

Comment: what's it supposed to do?

Comment: @ Richard Hodges   Partition the pack according to sizes indicated by the indices `Is...`  I've already finished it by adapting my code, but I'm trying to investigate this alleged ambiguity that mystified me earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching the order of specializations: before the zero version, next the generic integer version.

```
template <typename, typename, int> struct foo;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, typename... Us>
struct foo<P<Ts...>, std::tuple<P<Us...>>, 0> {};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, typename... Us, int I>
struct foo<P<Ts...>, std::tuple<P<Us...>>, I> : foo<P<Ts...>, std::tuple<P<Us...>>, I-1> {};
```

My clang++ (3.8.1) compile your original code without problem but my g++ (6.3.0) give a couple of errors and the second is

```
tmp_002-11,14,gcc,clang.cpp:21:8: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct foo<P<int, bool, char>, std::tuple<P<> >, 0>’
 struct foo<P<Ts...>, std::tuple<P<Us...>>, I> : foo<P<Ts...>, std::tuple<P<Us...>>, I-1> {};
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I don't know who's right: g++ or clang++.

But g++ is complaining that the generic integer specialization call (with `I==1`) the specialization with `I == 0` bat this specialization is "incomplete".

If you put the version with `I == 0` first, isn't incomplete anymore (from the point of view of the other specialization).

**-- EDIT --**

Regarding your "not reduced code", the problem seem the same (only for g++) but, in this case, you can't solve the problem changing the order of specializations because the following two specializations

```
template <template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest,
          typename... Ts, typename... Packs, std::size_t I, std::size_t... Is>
struct foo<P<First, Rest...>, std::tuple<P<Ts...>, Packs...>, I, Is...> 
   : foo<P<Rest...>, std::tuple<P<Ts..., First>, Packs...>, I-1, Is...>
 { };

template <template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest,
          typename... Ts, typename... Packs, std::size_t I, std::size_t J,
          std::size_t... Is>
struct foo<P<First, Rest...>, std::tuple<P<Ts...>, Packs...>, 0, I, J, Is...>
   : foo<P<Rest...>, std::tuple<P<First>, Packs..., P<Ts...>>, I-1, J, Is...>
{ };
```

depend (inherit) mutually from each other

Comment: Actually, in my original production code.  I did try switching the order of the specializations, and the ambiguity was still there.  Here I reduced the code a lot to show the problem more clearly.  I didn't expect that suddenly switching the order would now work after reducing the code.

Comment: @prestokeys - are you compiling with g++? if you try with clang++, you have the same error? Maybe you have oversimplified the code and the original production code is more complex and there is a real ambiguity. You should produce a minimal (but not so minimal) example that give error also switching the specializations

Comment: I added my non-reduced code in the question.  It shows the same ambiguity, and switching the order of the specializations does NOT solve the problem (with GCC 7.2).  It is a bit harder to read though.  But simplifying it might allow the same unexpected solution.

Comment: @prestokeys - I see; my clang++ compile without problem but I have the same problem with g++; in this case you can solve changing the order because there is a circular dependency.

Comment: @ max66  You mean can or can't?  And what is the ambiguity now?

Comment: @prestokeys - sorry: can't!

Comment: @prestokeys - not ambiguity, as far I understand. The problem (for g++) is thay the specialization with `0, I, J, Is...` use (inherit from) the specialization with `I-1, J, Is...` and vice versa.

Comment: @prestokeys - tried with wandbox and I can confirm that recent versions of clang++ (5.0.0 and Head 6.0.0) compile your code without problem and that recent versions of g++ (7.2.0 and Head 8.0.0) still give the same errors.